# puppeteer page.type() select second element/class

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, css-selectors, puppeteer

I'm trying to select and edit the first text input of the third div with "nxcard" class

this is the page structure :

```
<div>
  <div class="nxcard">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
    <form>
      <input type="number" />
      <input type="text" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="nxcard">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
    <form>
      <input type="number" />
      <input type="text" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="nxcard">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
    <form>
      <input type="number" />
      <!-- the input I want to select using pupeteer : -->
      <input type="text" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is the original code (how I'd have done it without puppeteer)

```js
  const loginCard = document.getElementsByClassName("nxCard")[2];
  const loginForm = loginCard.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
  const loginUserName = loginForm.getElementsByTagName("input")[1];
  loginUserName.value = "user1";
```

and this is how I've tried to do the same thing using puppeteer

```
  await page.type(".nxcard[2] form input[1]", "user1");
```

Comment: You don't need to do anything special in Puppeteer, just wrap your normal, working code in `page.evaluate()`. It might not be the most elegant option -- ideally, provide a relevant, minimal snippet of the actual site or the site you're working with so I can experiment and validate a possible solution. Pretty sure all of this can be written more cleanly. `.eutcard[5]` isn't really valid CSS. The first arg to `type` is eval'd as a plain `querySelector`, nothing really special or specific to Puppeteer. Also, if you get an error, it's a good idea to share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it using the following css selector

```js
await page.type(".nxcard:last-child input:nth-child(1)" , "user1")
```

src : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp